# Python - Importing pandas in console works but not when running script

Tags: python, email, pandas, import

I've been working with anaconda3/python3.5 and pandas for over a year and all of sudden when I run my script outside the console, I get a import error for pandas particularly the dependency email.parser. I get No module named 'email.parser';'email' is not a package. However importing in the console works fine. I'm not running any other environment

Comment: print your pythonpath on both environments and verify it is the same

Comment: When i run python in the console vs run script, I'm using two environments?  In sys.environ, I have all the proper path, how do I check path for the other environment. @guilhernecgs

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem today. You're missing a specific path. Found that if you start your python interpreter and do `import os`, you can do `os.environ`. You'll notice that there are several paths set in the PATH variable. Copy/paste the entire PATH line into your script. That worked for me. Also, remember to remove string single quotes (e.g., ').