# nodejs child_process package fails to work for python script only when using certain imports

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pandas, electron

I am writing a simple Electron app on Windows that uses several python files utilizing various python machine learning libraries. My goal at this point is to simply click a button which executes a python script that either stores output to a file local to the directory of the python script or returns output to the Electron app--either way is fine.

Using a few different methods (exec, spawn, etc). I have had success calling the python script, and have had the python script correctly write test values to files and correctly return test values to my applications.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const pyProg = spawn('python', ['./../path/to/pyfile/cmd_test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'...], {detached: true});

pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
alert(data);
console.log(data.toString());
});
```

The issue is, once I import either of two necessary libraries for my python script (pandas and sklearn), the script halts and neither writes to file nor returns output. This is not the case when importing certain other libraries like numpy or sys. If I comment out the pandas (or sklearn) import, everything works fine.

```
import sys
import ast
import numpy as np
#import pandas as pd
```

Whats more, if I manually call the same command line command that the Electron app executes from the same directory as the Electron app itself, the program runs correctly, and the both the file writing and output work correctly, regardless of whether or not I import pandas or sklearn.

```
python ./../path/to/pyfile/cmd_test.py arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like python is not finding the installed packages.

The difference between sys, ast and numpy with pandas is that the first 3 are standard libraries and pandas is a third party. If you installed it via pip try adding the installed libraries path to your python path. Put this on top of the python

- If you are using python 3:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append(C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3X[-32]\site-packages)
  ```

Notice how there is an X and a -32 between brackets. The X should be your python 3 sub-version and you should put the -32 if you installed the 32 bit version of python.

- If you are using 2.7:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append(c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages)
  ```

This are the default routes for windows they could be different in your computer if you set that in the installation

- If you are on a unix-like system then add this:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append(/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages)
  ```

Notice the X and Y this should be the version and sub-version respectively. If you don't know your python version just execute in the console/terminal:

```
python --version
```

It should return something like this:

```
Python 3.7.1
```

Use only the first 2 numbers for the path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using anaconda, and I have pandas in 'C:\\Users\\*\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages'. I verified that this directory is on my sys.path for my interpreter. Do you have any other thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: For what I had read the interpreter automatically adds those paths, but the python executable doesn't. So it should work if is the file that adds it.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552453/python-importing-pandas-in-console-works-but-not-when-running-script) is another example of this problem.

Comment: Even using the sys.path.append explicitly to the file to run does not work. There is definitely some path issue here, but it is difficult to say what it is.

Comment: did you try adding just the site-packages or directly to pandas?